# If a ≡ b (mod n) and m|n, then a ≡ b (mod m)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Prove the following, for positive integers $m$ and $n$.
If $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ and $m\mid n$, then $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$.

This seems to me to be simple transitivity with the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic. 
$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ and $m\mid n$ means that $n \mid a - b$ so there is an integer k such that $kn = a - b$. Since $m|n$ there is an $l$ such that $lm = n$. Thus by substitution $klm = a - b$. Which means that $m \mid a - b$, this proves that $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$.

My question is firstly is this proof sound? And also if there is any more detail or a more concise way of writing this proof. I am new to proof writing in this format.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's perfect. The only shorter way would be without writing down the quotients, using the transitivity of the divisibility relation (writing directly $m|n$ and $n|b-a$ therefore $m|b-a$).

Comment: Yes.  That's a perfect proof.  It's a matter of style a personal comprehension what is more convincing but when I think of what these *mean* I find $a\equiv b\mod n;m|n \implies a = b + kn= b+kjm \implies a\equiv b \mod m$ hits my in the gut just slightly harder, but that is just me.  The proofs are both exactly the same and rely on definitions and ... when you think about them, should be intuitively obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect proof. This is sufficiently concise.

Comment: Beware of posting "answers" that are much shorter than the Questions to which they respond.  Surely there is more to be said than repeating what was already stated in Comments by others?

Comment: Accepted to move the solution to solved. Let me know if this is the best way I should do this. Thank you all.